# AWS Amplify GraphQL API changing the nested level depth for codegenerator

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

In [AWS Amplify CLI](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/) when you add a GrpahQL API with

```
amplify add api
```

you are asked for the max level depth of the generated code. The default nested level is 3.

In my case it turns out that the max depth is not enough and I need to increase it.

Is there a way to do that?

I'we tried to run

```
amplify update api
```

However I wasn't asked again about the maximum level depth of the generated code during the process of the update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution in [this github asnwer](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-codegen/issues/64#issuecomment-774338754).
Turns out that the file `.graphqlconfig.yml` is responsible for the AWS Amplify GraphQL API.
The property `projects.YOUR-API-NAME.extensions.amplify.maxDepth` is responsible for changing the nested level depth for the codegenerator. Now my `.graphqlconfig.yml` file looks in the following way and it works:

```
projects:
  YOUR-API-NAME:
    schemaPath: amplify/backend/api/zlmvp/build/schema.graphql
    includes:
      - src/graphql/**/*.ts
    excludes:
      - ./amplify/**
    extensions:
      amplify:
        codeGenTarget: typescript
        generatedFileName: src/API.ts
        docsFilePath: src/graphql
        maxDepth: 5
extensions:
  amplify:
    version: 3
```